# Is it plagiarism if you combine different algorithms to form one algorithm?

Tags: publications, graduate-school

Im doing a paper where i use a system to combine rules and algorithms from different studies to form a complete program. The ideas were combined and i made a program from that combined idea, now th program itself was made by me and I used solutions which are not exactly the same such as using shortcuts and other functions in matlab. The original papers were all in 1980s, and i was wondering if it is plagiarism to use their algorithms. In my methodology i explained thoroughly their method.

Answer (score 3):

Combining various things to form one new thing is valid research. If your algorithm is a hybrid of 2 others, you need of course to mention these 2 and their authors as well (which you seem to indicate that you are doing). Otherwise you risk your readers thinking that everything in the hybrid algorithm is new, especially since they were developed way back. 
Long story short, if you're acknowledging the work you are basing your approach on, you're being a good student. No plagiarism there.

Comment: Thanks i was worried since im using a rule based system and im worried that it wont be valid to just combine them. What i did in the methodology was explain that the system will use combinations of different methods and theories and explain their method in each phase. At the very beginning of the methodology i stated that i based the new system using the different authora work , i included their names, is that enough citation?

Comment: @MarkCruz Presumably those algorithms were published in some manner. If they were novel works by the authors, you should make some effort to find and cite those papers. If they were only software implementations of work developed previously, you should make some effort to cite those original developments as well as the implementations by the authors, if you used their code and not your own implementation of the original algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you cite the former works sufficially. Besides, this is exactly how science works. New  ideas are built upon the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

Never. In computer science, the use of libraries is perfectly valid and always encouraged. On one end of the spectrum, you'll write an algorithm that's super useful to people and that's gonna be cited by everyone. On the other, doing {Algo1(); Algo2()} is still perfectly legal, just no one's gonna read you. Full period.